# How to count 2 or 3 letter words in a string using asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to count 2 or 3 letter words of a string using asp csharp, eg.

```
string value="This is my string value";
```

and output should look like this

```
2 letter words = 2  
3 letter words = 0  
4 letter words = 1
```

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The solution is check each item's length with a loop! and then increment each record with `word_counter[len(i)]++`.

Comment: Check `Regex` and `string.Split` - it might be more convenient way to do that as we as code would be shorter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

- split sentence by space to get array of words
- group them by length of word (and order by that length)
- iterate through every group and write letter count and number of words with that letter count

**code**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
...

var words = value.Split(' ');
var groupedByLength = words.GroupBy(w => w.Length).OrderBy(x => x.Key);
foreach (var grp in groupedByLength)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} letter words: {1}", grp.Key, grp.Count()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to decide what counts as a word. A naive approach is to split the string with spaces, but this will also count commas. Another approach is to use the following regex

```
\b\w+?\b
```

and collect all the matches.

Now you got all the words in a `words` array, we can write a LINQ query:

```
var query = words.Where(x => x.Length >= 2 && x.Length <= 4)
                 .GroupBy(x => x.Length)
                 .Select(x => new { CharCount = x.Key, WordCount = x.Count() });
```

Then you can print the query out like this:

```
query.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

This prints:

```
{ CharCount = 4, WordCount = 1 }
{ CharCount = 2, WordCount = 2 }
```

You can write some code yourself to produce a more formatted output.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly
You can do it using dictionary

First split the string by space in this case

```
 string value = "This is my string value";
 string[] words = value.Split(' ');
```

Then loop trough array of words and set the length of each word as a **key** of dictionary, note that I've used `string` as a **key**, but you can modify this to your needs.

```
Dictionary<string, int> latteWords = new Dictionary<string,int>();
for(int i=0;i<words.Length;i++)
{
    string key = words[i].Length + " letter word";
    if (latteWords.ContainsKey(key))
        latteWords[key] += 1;
    else 
    latteWords.Add(key, 1);
}
```

And the output would be

```
foreach(var ind in latteWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ind.Key + " = " + ind.Value);
}
```

Modify this by wish.